# How to safely dispose an instance of a client returned from a singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, singleton, dispose

Given I have the following code which is provided as a singleton lifetime service through .net core, how can I safely dispose of a client (it does implement IDisposable) and the create a new one. I'm concerned once I call Dispose the old client, it will be removed and in the meantime any callers that retrieved the client will be pointing at a client that is now disposed.

```
public class MyClientFactory: IMyClientFactory
{
    private Client { get; set; }

    public async Task<IMyClient> GetClient()
    {
        if (this.Client != null && DoSomeChecksToSeeIfValid())
        {
            return this.Client;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Client?.Dispose();

            this.Client = new MyClient(await DoSomethingToGetNewCredentials());

            return this.Client;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the lifetime it's best not to return an instance of the object.
But if this doesn't suit you you can use the event model.

```
public interface IMyClientManager
{
     void Do(Action<MyClient> action);
}
public interface IMyClient : IDisposable
{
    
}
public sealed class MyClient: IMyClient
{
    public delegate void DisposeHandle();

    public event DisposeHandle DisposeEvent;

    private bool _isDispose;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDispose)
            DisposeEvent?.Invoke();
        _isDispose = true;
    }
}

public class MyClientManager : IMyClientManager
{
    private MyClient Client { get; set; }
    private object _sync = new object();
    private bool DoSomeChecksToSeeIfValid()
    {
        return this.Client != null;
    }

    public void Do(Action<MyClient> action)
    {
        // you can  create connection pull
        while (!DoSomeChecksToSeeIfValid())
        {
            InitClient();
            //todo: connect or setup
        }

        action.Invoke(this.Client);
    }

    private void InitClient()
    {
        if (this.Client == null)
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                this.Client ??= new MyClient();
                this.Client.DisposeEvent += Client_DisposeEvent;
            }

        }
    }

    public MyClient Create()
    {
        // you can  create connection pull
        while (!DoSomeChecksToSeeIfValid())
        {
            InitClient();
            
        }

        return this.Client;
    }

    private void Client_DisposeEvent()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            this.Client.DisposeEvent-= Client_DisposeEvent;
            this.Client = null;
        }

    }
}
```